# Cannot Import BatchNormalization when using ImageAI

Tags: python, tensorflow

I was following a tutorial about object detection, and it gave me this code:

```
from imageai.Detection import ObjectDetection
import os

execution_path = os.getcwd()

detector = ObjectDetection()
detector.setModelTypeAsRetinaNet()
detector.setModelPath( os.path.join(execution_path , "resnet50_coco_best_v2.1.0.h5"))
detector.loadModel()
detections = detector.detectObjectsFromImage(input_image=os.path.join(execution_path , "image.jpg"), output_image_path=os.path.join(execution_path , "imagenew.jpg"))

for eachObject in detections:
    print(eachObject["name"] , " : " , eachObject["percentage_probability"] )
```

The problem is, it kept giving me an error like this:
`ImportError: cannot import name 'BatchNormalization' from 'keras.layers.normalization'`

I searched around, and I think its to do with my tensorflow version, but I never found a solution that worked.

Answer (score 2):

You have to import Batch Normalization from tf.keras.layers

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tf.keras.layers import BatchNormalization
```

Hope , this [Documentation](https://keras.io/api/layers/normalization_layers/batch_normalization/) may help you better.

If my answer finds you well..upvote
.

.
Happy Learning

Answer (score 1):

When you get the error message there should be a directory given to a **ini**.py file. Open it with your IDE and past this line. It somehow worked for me.

```
from keras.layers.normalization.batch_normalization import BatchNormalization
```